# Force a $http.get to run every time the view is loaded - Angular

Tags: angularjs

I have a view within my App which does a database pull to show a user images they have previously uploaded.

**The problem** is that another view allows them to upload new images, but when switching back to the view of their uploaded images, they have to do a full page refresh to see their new uploads.

**The question** is how can I force the `$http.get` to run every time the view is loaded?

This is what I am trying but is not doing what I think it should:

```
capApp.controller('myUploadedPhotos', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.nameFilter = "";
    $http.get("/ajax/myUploadedPhotos.php", { cache: false})
      .success(function(response) {
        $scope.photos = response;
      });
  });
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Did you look in the console to make sure the request really wasn't cached? Seems like your `get` should run it when that controller is loaded.

Comment: Ahh, you are correct - my bad for not actually looking - do I need to put a watch in I guess? The .get() is running but not updating the view

Comment: You can append a unique timestamp to the url to bust the cache: `"/ajax/myUploadedPhotos.php" + new Date().getTime()` - I'd leave your `{ cache: false}` because that will prevent the Angular caching.

Comment: All good, thanks! - if you want to add as answer I'll happily accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks correct so possibly the request is cached from the server? You can try appending a random string to your url to break the cache. e.g.

```
"/ajax/myUploadedPhotos.php" + new Date().getTime()
```

After thinking about it, I think you can also remove the `{ cache: false}` because Angular also won't be able to cache the request if the timestamp changes. The old requests would just be sitting around somewhere taking up memory.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite understand your question, but there isn't any issues with next initialization behaviour:

```
(function(angular) {
    var capApp = angular.module('yourModule', []);

    capApp.controller('myUploadedPhotos', ['$scope', '$http',
        function ($scope, $http) {
            $scope.nameFilter = "";

            $scope.actions = angular.extend($scope.actions || {}, {
                init: function () {
                    return $http.get("/ajax/myUploadedPhotos.php", {cache: false}).then(
                        function (response) {
                            $scope.photos = response;
                        }, function (reason) {
                            console.log('Error occured: ' + reason);
                        });
                }
            });

            // You could even use it in $watch
            $scope.actions.init();
        }
    ]);
})(angular);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me - i changed .then() to .success() but still the same problem - I need the `$http.get` to run every time the view is loaded